# Printing Simplified Corpus to Json File

Tags: python, json, nltk, corpus

I'm trying to print out the Brown corpus with a simplified tagset to a file. This is the code I'm using, and its just ending up with a blank file.

```
import json
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown

brown_sents = nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_sents(tagset="universal")

for sent in brown_sents:
  with open('brown_corpus.txt', 'a') as outfile:
     json.dumps(sent, outfile)
```

Comment: Don't reopen the file for every sentence, that's slow and just ugly. And if you run your program a second time it'll just append to the existing contents. Open it once with mode `"w"`, write everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.dumps()` is meant for returning a `str`, not for writing to an open file. Use

```
json.dump(sent, outfile)
```

instead, and you should be fine.